# Global Temporary Table Concurrency

Tags: oracle, concurrency

I have a global temp table which is set as delete on commit. How does it behave on concurrency issue? I mean what happens if another session wants to use that global temporary table? The answer will probably not be "they share the same data".

Now, if my guess is correct :), is the table locked until the first connection commits, or does the dbms create a global temp table for each connection? ( something like an instance of the table? )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#sthref7482):

> The data in a temporary table is visible only to the session that inserts the data into the table.

Each session will have its logical **independent** copy of the temporary table.

Since you can not see other sessions' data and since Oracle deals with locks at the row level, you can not be blocked by other sessions' DML. Concurrent DML (Insert, Delete, Update) won't affect other sessions.

Only DDL will need a lock on the table (ie: ALTER TABLE...)

Comment: I'm interested in this question -- are you saying that global temp tables are not a good way to lock a set of rows?  If I have two threads that need to operate on a list of entries given a certain time, can global temp tables help each thread grab a section of this list of entries without overlapping?

Comment: @michael: each thread would have its own session (or they could not run in parallel), so they won't see each other's temp data. Temp tables alone won't allow you to lock rows without overlap, you will need other features. See [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5907003/119634).